# Why does an unordered sequential stream always return the same thing to me when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, java-stream, unordered

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}


list.stream().unordered().limit(50_000_000).skip(25_000_000).findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println); // 25000000 always
```

> For **sequential** streams, the presence or absence of an encounter order does not affect performance, **only determinism**.

But no matter how many times I run this code, I always get the same result, which does not agree with the above statement. Why?

Comment: Why do you think that your example "doesn't agree" with the quote? There is no guarantee that it will return `25000000`. Neither there is a guarantee that it *won't* simply return `25000000`, given the nature of your stream.

Comment: Your code works correctly. It should return some element from your list, and so it does. You have no guarantees beyond that. This also means that *theoretically* with the next Java version it may behave differently. I’d be surprised if it does, but it’s not to be ruled out.

Comment: *unordered* does not imply *shuffled*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unordered simply says "don't bother ordering this stream." It is there to prevent final ordering operations that are unnecessary and therefore might incur additional overhead and impact performance. An example of how this might be used would be joining different pieces of an ordered stream in a parallel operation. For an ordered stream, having to wait for certain threads to finish processing to preserve order could take longer than if the output of each thread was used as it finished.

But as was said/implied in the comments, no operation goes out of its way to change the order of the stream unless it is specifically directed to (e.g. sort). The output of a sort operation would be marked as ordered because order preservation is required.

Streams are initially ordered as values are placed on the stream as they are encountered.

```
int ch = IntStream.range(0,2).unordered().spliterator().characteristics();
System.out.println(ch&Spliterator.ORDERED);
```

prints `0` so ordered bit not set

Set's are unordered data structures so sorting forces them to be ordered.

```
int ch =Set.of(1,2,3,4,5).stream().sorted().spliterator().characteristics();
System.out.println(ch&Spliterator.ORDERED);
```

prints `16` so ordered bit (bit 4) is set.

Comment: so is there any point in using List<Integer>.stream().unordered()?

Comment: And is there any point in using unordered method with sequential streams?

Comment: With regard to the first question, Sure. If you are doing some operation on the items in parallel and don't care if the order is maintained you may gain some improved performance. But there is setup overhead in doing parallel streams so it may take a very large list to realize any improved performance.  As far as sequential streams go I can't think of any advantage.  Streams by their very nature are ordered and simply saying you don't care won't affect that order.

Comment: Remember that order doesn't imply a specific action to be performed.  It is used to assess what algorithms may be applied down stream.  For some set, `set.stream().ordered()` does not magically sort the set.  It just relays information how to properly process the items and maintain the order.

Comment: "As far as sequential streams go I can't think of any advantage. Streams by their very nature are ordered and simply saying you don't care won't affect that order" - So using the unordered() method in sequential streams doesn't make sense?

Comment: Correct.  It doesn't make sense to me.  But others may have more insight.

Comment: Source code is to express *intent*. It doesn’t matter whether there is an effect under the hood when you call `unordered()`. The purpose is to make clear to future readers that you do not care about an encounter order in the subsequent operations. Performance advantages are only a nice-to-have. There are theoretical benefits even for a sequential operation, e.g. `.unordered().limit(50_000_000).skip(25_000_000)` could be optimized to `.unordered().limit(25_000_000)`, as an unordered stream doesn’t have to skip the first 25 mio elements. `.unordered().sorted()` does not have to be stable, etc.